# how to match javascript onSubmit with jQuery submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onsubmit, form-submit

i have a form

```
<form id="add_list_form">
    ...
</form>
```

then with jQuery i can do:

```
$("#add_list_form").submit(function(){
    $(this).serializeArray()
});
```

and this will work.

but if i use `onSubmit`:

```
<form onsubmit="addListForm(event);">
    ...
</form>

function addListForm(e)
{
    $(this).serializeArray()
}
```

it doesn't seem to work, in my case i get serialized some other form from my page witch i think is an bug

Any ideas how can i accomplish the same effect like jQuery `submit` event?

Comment: What's the problem with doing it the first way?

Comment: Not 100% sure but aren't you suppose to copy the way you wrote the event? so it should be `addListForm(event)` in both bits of the code I presume?

Comment: @MattBall, there are some hardware buttons that don't seem to like jquery submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access `this` using `onsubmmit`, pass the source object (`form`) using `this` to `addListForm`

```
<form onsubmit="addListForm(this, event);">
    ...
</form>

function addListForm(form, e)
{
    $(form).serializeArray()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `FORM object` inside `function` so how can `$(this)` will get desired `FORM`.

Try

```
<form onsubmit="addListForm(this.form);">
    ...
</form>

function addListForm(form)
{
    $(form).serializeArray()
}
```

you send more than one `argument` inside `function`.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 <form onsubmit="addListForm(this);">
        ...
    </form>
```

or

```
<form action="addListForm(this);">
            ...
        </form>
```